# DPA 4060s-ways of placing them during field recording

Tags: microphone, field-recording

Hi,

I borrowed DPA 4060 omni mics from a friend to try them and do some field recordings.

Does anyone uses them for the same purpose?

Could you suggest a way to place them when going out on the field? A hanger would be a good idea but please share with me any other ways of placing them during recording.

I will use them in combination with a Tascam DR-100 recorder.

thank you very much,

panjethro

Comment: These are vocal mics arent they? Lapels?

Answer (score 1):

Hi panjethro, 
if you mean what stereo-system to use then AB or a baffle-system might be a good idea. Two very important issues in field recording are wind and handling noise. If you have some kind of a zeppelin/ blimp then that would make a small AB-setup possible and also cure those 2 problems.

The width between the mics you need depends on the source you are recording, just listen through headphones and move the mics apart until it start sounding "right".

You can also build your own windscreen on a budget, something like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SudmkbL06zg

Comment: I recommend getting the small furries from bubblebee http://www.bubblebeeindustries.com/
excellent wind reduction, get the right size and colour, the're about 50 euros per set..

Answer (score 0):

Check out Tim Prebble's [DIY mini mic clips](http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/vietnam-01-first-impressions) - very practicle and cheap!

Answer (score 0):

I have a stereo pair myself. I've mounted them in a blimp, I've used them as binaurals, I've hung them out a hi-rise window, taped them to a brick wall, under a car hood... you get the picture

They're small, they take a ton of SPL, and they sound great. Use them however you see fit to capture the sound you're looking for. Mine came with the micro dot to XLR adapters, so wireless units are unnecessary. I just plug them directly into a field mixer / recorder.

To mount them, I've had a lot of success using [BluTack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FGLX72) on the bottom of a [universal mount](http://www.dv247.com/microphones/dpa-dmm0007-universal-surface-mount--45688). If you don't have one of these mounts, improvise, assess the recordings, and modify your approach. Handling / cable noise would be the chief concerns in improvising a mount. Even without the universal mount, I'd recommend having some BluTack. Highly useful stuff.